# SQL Server - set field to one text value if NULL, append different text value if not

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, sql-update

I'm using the following query to append text to the end of a variable length text field of comma-separated values:

```
UPDATE dbo.Sources
SET CatCustom = RTRIM(CatCustom) + ', LRR01'
WHERE SourceID IN (1,2,3,4,5,8,9,44,63,45,101,102,222,344)
```

What I've discovered is that many of the CatCustom fields are NULL and therefore I'm ending up with ', LRR01' inside those fields - the leading comma and space is not desirable.  So how would I enhance this query to say

```
> If the CatCustom field is NULL, set it to 'LRR01',  else SET CatCustom = RTRIM(CatCustom) + ', LRR01'?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`concat_ws`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql) is exactly what you need:

```
UPDATE dbo.Sources
SET    CatCustom = CONCAT_WS(', ', RTRIM(CatCustom), 'LRR01')
WHERE  SourceID IN (1,2,3,4,5,8,9,44,63,45,101,102,222,344)
```